# Get all elements from array if key of date is less/more than

Tags: php, count

I have an array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [date] => 2014-07-26 10:36:52
        [nr_ref] => DX35359GC
        [nr_invoice] => 2014/07/359235ASF
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [date] => 2014-07-27 11:58:47
        [nr_ref] => PXI-s953953.35935.2
        [nr_invoice] => 2014/35614/14014
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [date] => 2014-07-27 11:59:19
        [nr_ref] => R03835-3580533
        [nr_invoice] => 2014/07/359235ASF
    )
```

How to count only these items which date is > `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

I've ended up with code:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if( strtotime( $v['date'] ) > strtotime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ) ) {
        echo count( $k );
    }
}
```

But this do not work. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have very huge array I would optimize bansi answer to:

```
$itmcount = 0; // initialize a counter variable
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if( strtotime( $v['date'] ) >  $time) {
        $itmcount++; //increment counter
    }
}
echo $itmcount;
```

Because if you foreach is evaluated more than one second you will have two different strtotime(date()) values in conditional statement. For example:

```
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) . "\n"; // 1406465191
sleep(1);
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // 1406465192
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort I will use var cache.

Answer (score 3):

You should do something like this.

```
$itmcount = 0; // initialize a counter variable
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if( strtotime( $v['date'] ) > strtotime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ) ) {
        $itmcount++; //increment counter
    }
}
echo $itmcount;
```

Comment: @RafcioKowalsky, if this has answered your question could you mark it answered? :)